# The symbol \hbar is not recognized (but shows up as "h") when using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

I am using XeLaTeX with the packages `fontspec,xunicode,xlxtra` (which I believe is pretty standard) to process my documents into a PDF file with the TeX Gyre Pagella font.

I have been doing so successfully for quite some time, but when using the standard LaTeX symbol `\hbar`, upon processing an error is thrown

> LaTeX Warning: Command \hbar invalid in math mode on input line 86

and the symbol appears instead as a regular "h" which partially overlaps with the previous character.

Here is a minimal code example:

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra}  
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
hbar by itself:  $\hbar$\\
hbar with a preceeding character:   $o\hbar$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of code?

Comment: Minimal code added; thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with `xunicode`.

Mixing Computer Modern Math with Pagella (Palatino) is not a good choice (but this is not related to the problem).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % get Palatino math  
\usepackage{fontspec} % xunicode is not needed, nor xltxtra
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % syntax compatible with LuaLaTeX
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

% Magic formula for make \hbar not throwing a spurious message
% However, \hbar won't work in text mode, which should not be a problem
\expandafter\let\expandafter\hbar\csname ?-\string\hbar\endcsname
% End of magic code

\begin{document}
hbar by itself:  $\hbar$\\
hbar with a preceeding character:   $o\hbar$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out that you do need the Palatino math font in order to get the \hbar to work.  (Commenting out \usepackage{mathpazo} breaks that \hbar)

Comment: @WilliamKennerly You have to call `fontspec` with the option `no-math`, I believe, if `mathpazo` is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can put
`\newcommand{\hbarhorizline}{\mathchar'26\mkern-7mu h}`
in preamble and then used this new command `\hbarhorizline` in the formulas.
If one has in the formula any symbol directly before it, then one needs to add space before `\hbarhorizline` to avoid overlap in this way `$G\ \hbarhorizline$`.